# How to track down an unexpected token in JSON?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax-error, backtracking

```
undefined:13
]
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 267
```

I have found many similar questions and I assume the problem is that `JSON.parse` returns incorrect data with an extra `]` symbol. Probably HTML instead of JSON or something. But the problem is that I can't figure out how to track down where exactly the problem comes from? I have multiple js files with many `JSON.parse` included. The answer should be in my error message but I can't figure out where to look at. Line 267 is definitely a wrong answer because it is an empty line in all my files. Thanks.

Full error:

```
undefined:13
]
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ] in JSON at position 267
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at mybp (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/apple/Desktop/UTESTTWO/app/bp.js:39:1), <anonymous>:109:25)
    at getaccountdata (/Users/apple/Desktop/UTESTTWO/app/bp.js:64:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Desktop/UTESTTWO/app/bp.js:351:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/apple/Desktop/UTESTTWO/automatic.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
```

Comment: Are you able to paste the json file

Comment: Do `getaccountdata` or `mybp` ring some bells? (I mean: are this functions written by you? You could look there for an error and add console.log before the JSON.parse.)

Comment: *"...and I assume the problem is that `JSON.parse` returns incorrect data with an extra `]` symbol.."* I guarantee you that assumption is incorrect, for two reasons: 1. `JSON.parse` [isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). 2. `JSON.parse` is for **parsing** JSON (turning a string into the result of parsing it), not for *stringifying* it. That's `JSON.stringify` (which also isn't broken).

Comment: The way to find and fix this problem is to put a breakpoint on the line of code where the error occurs, then run your page/app to the point where the breakpoint gets hit. Then look at what you've passed into `JSON.parse`, with particular attention to what's at position 267 in that string, but also what goes before. If you're getting that error, you have unbalanced `[]` in the code (more `]` than `[`).

Comment: if you look below the first line, you will see the stack trace which tells you exactly where the problem is coming from

Comment: @SpeedOfSpin the only local json file is the following one: 
`{
    
        "id": "xxxx25332",
        "key": "xxx84",
        "cookie": "user-id=xxxwt; stack[hash]=xxxcd; stack[user]=xxx32",
        "token": "5xxxcc",
        "mkey": "xxxZ0",
        "user_id": "xxxawt"
}`

Comment: @RisingSun you mean this? `at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

Comment: @narra_kk yes. now just keep going down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is a bit like playing 21 questions.  Remove or comment out calls to half of your code and see if the error persists.  That will help you tell which half contains the error.  Once you know which half it is, then split the code in that half again. Repeat the process and keep reducing your code in half until you narrow it down to the section that contains the error.

When you don't have much else to go on you sometimes must resort to reduction techniques like this to narrow your scope.